# Does Webpack plugin for MicroFrontends support flutter web app be used as MicroFrontend inside angular app?

Tags: angular, webpack, flutter-web, webpack-module-federation

I have angular application which works independently. Also there is a flutter web build for a certain feature which runs independently. I would like to use the flutter web build as a micro frontend which can be viewed in angular shell application using angular routes. Was thinking of using Webpack module federation plugin to do so. Is this possible to achieve using Webpack module federation plugin?

Since there are not many resources regarding Webpack plugin to be used with flutter, any help will be greatly appreciated.